# vim - :loadview from a specific file

Tags: vim, folding

I've recently started to use vim and want to learn how to save views into files (most importantly for saving folds).

Let's say I'm editing a file called `int_array.c` and I've finished adding lots of useful folds.

When I execute the following command:

```
:mkview int_array.v
```

A file called int_array.v gets created that seems to contain the data for all the folds and such. Here's an example of the code in the folder:

```
12,44fold
48,56fold
63,90fold
...
```

Which corresponds to the start/end lines of my folds.

However, when I close and reopen `int_array.c`, obviously my folds are gone, so I run:

```
:loadview int_array.v
```

But nothing happens. No folds are in the document at all: I ran the two commands:

```
:%foldc
```

and

```
:%foldo
```

which close/open all the folds respectively, but nothing happened, so I conclude that the folds didn't load. (I tested the commands on a file with folds, and they are the correct commands).

Note: Just using `:mkview` and `:loadview` to use vim's internal buffer works great, but I'd love to be able to move the view files across machines, so this won't do.

I tried this process on both my local computer and on the instructional machines available to me through ssh, but neither worked. I also tried saving the view to many different file names, but to no avail.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

edit: if needed, I can show the contents of `int_array.v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create views just like you have done:

```
:mkview %.v
```

However `:loadview` only accepts a number, not a file path. View files are just a bunch of vim commands so you just `:source` it.

```
:source %.v
```