# Loading view file (created by mkview!) not being sourced/loaded by an autocommand event

Tags: vim

Refering to this post [load views from specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497623/vim-loadview-from-a-specific-file) I'd like to retain/keep all my folds when copying my files to different machines by saving and than sourcing the viewfile automatically by an autocommand.

```
augroup WriteAndSourceViews
    autocmd!

    " this one here works perfect fine and every time the mkview command is executed and the file created
    autocmd BufWritePre *.* execute "mkview! " . expand('<afile>:p:h') . "/." . expand('<afile>:t') . ".vimview"

    " this command doesn't work with any of the events... manually by command line it work fine though...
    autocmd BufRead,BufWinEnter,BufReadPost,FilereadPost *.* execute "silent! source " . expand('%:p:h') . "/." . expand('%:t') . ".vimview"
augroup END
```

Why no of the events for sourcing the file are working?

Comment: What does "None of those events work" mean? What do you expect? What do you get instead? Is it the event that doesn't "work" or the autocommand associated to that event?

Comment: As stated, none of the events work. Running ":execute "silent! source " . expand('%:p:h') . "/." . expand('%:t') . ".vimview" manually as command works well. I expect the view file to be sourced automatically when opening a file.

Comment: The usual events for "opening a file" are `BufNewFile,BufRead`. FWIW, there is already `:help :loadview` (linked from `:help :mkview`) for that so why are you (poorly) reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Sure, I know about `:loadview` but I need to transfer my folds when copying files to another machines. Check my updated post and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46497721/13144033).